# How add variables to string for TTF_RenderText_Solid

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning to do output with TTF files and was wondering how i can output the font using variables with strings?

For example, i have the position of the `mouseX` and `mouseY` defined as `Int`.

I want to output a string like:

Mouse X: `mouseX`, Mouse Y: `mouseY`

This is where I output the text:

```
 font_surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font_file,"MouseX: //need to add variable MouseY: //here too",font_color);
```

Does any one know the syntax to incorporate the variables to this function with the string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used SDL_ttf, I used [`stringstream`](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~breech/progteam/stringstream.html) to build my strings. You could also use sprintf but that's generally discouraged in a C++ app.

```
#include <sstream>
...
std::stringstream s;
s << "Mouse xpos: " << xpos << " Mouse ypos: " << ypos;
fontSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font_file, s.str().c_str(), font_color);
```

`.str()` produces an STL string, and then `.c_str()` returns a `const char*` to the guts of the STL string, which SDL, a pretty firmly C library, expects.